BLDC motor phase sensor
I've been working on a 4 wheel differential drive robot. It has 4 brushless motors attached to gearboxes, driven by RC ESCs. I have some of these Hobbywing RPM sensors attached to two wires of each motor controller to find the motor speed. They output pulses that I read with an interrupt on an MCU and count the pulses to get the velocity.
One of the sensors is DOA and I can't help but wonder if I can just use a transistor to do the same thing. The signal in voltage is ~12v, the signal out is 3.3v.
Here's a link to the product in question: https://www.hobbywingdirect.com/products/rpm-sensor
Can I use a simple transistor to read when any two wires of the brushless motor are energized? Do I need to worry about back EMF or anything?
One cool thing I noticed is that the encoder still output signal if I rotate the motors with my hand.

You might find it has a low pass filter in there as well so it doesn't output the PWM the ESC uses to control the motor speed.
